# How to create an eBay deeplink with affiliate ID?

Tags: html, deep-linking, ebay-api

Does anyone know if it is possible to create a deeplink to ebay products but that also pass the affiliate ID to ebay?

Today the affiliate links ebay provides are:
http://rover.ebay.com/rover/0...

Is it possible to use them in deep linking so the product will open in the eBay app but also track my affiliate ID?

Comment: Ever figure this one out?

Answer (score 0):

I went thru this recently with the eBay native app.  At the time of this answer the native app does not support affiliate IDs and only very basic two URL scheme parameters. You can search and launch to a particular item only.   I just verified this with eBay dev support this week in fact!

Here's a page link that talk to what is available since eBay does not seem to doc it, accurate for the current app version on iOS at the time of this answer.

[Wikipedia page on Mobile App Deep Linking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_deep_linking)

Comment: fixed the dead 404 link and replaced with wikipedia that should be more durable.